# Position versus position vector

Tags: vectors

I would argue that the notion of *position vector* is useless, but at the same time it makes things simpler. For example, if we state that $\mathbf{r}$ (function of coordinates ($q^1,q^2,q^3$)) is a position vector, then the chain rule reads:
$$ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q^i}\mathrm{d}q^i$$
and the vector nature of $\mathbf{r}$ follows in $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ and $\partial \mathbf{r}$: if $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector, then $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ and $\partial \mathbf{r}$ are also vectors.

Instead, consider that $M$ is a position, function of the coordinates ($q^1,q^2,q^3$). Accordingly, $\mathbf{dM}$ is a vector as the difference between two points. However, in the chain rule expression:
$$\mathbf{dM}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}}{\partial q^i}\mathrm{d}q^i$$
how do we know which quantity is a vector? Is it $\partial\mathbf{M}$ or $\partial\mathbf{M}/\partial q^i$ or $\mathrm{d}q^i$? In other words, if I use an arrow on $\vec{dM}$, where should I place the arrow on the right hand side? And why?

Comment: I cannot quite follow you. What is a *position* other than a vector? What do you mean with "the vector nature follows in $\mathrm d\mathbf r$ and $\partial\mathbf r$"?

Comment: When you express something in terms of vectors you lose some specificity, but have the potential to gain insight. Basis dependent (cartesian) formulations of mathematics are very powerful for some computations. But basis independent formulations express important symmetries and can capture a bigger picture.

Comment: @M.Winter A vector belongs to a vector space (you can add two vectors) while a position is a point which belongs to an affine space (you cannot add two positions, but you can create a vector by subtracting two positions).

Comment: Do I understand you corectly? You have an element $\mathbf r$ or $M\in\Bbb R^3$ and you want to know whether it is a vector or an affine point? Mathematically speaking there is no difference. It is not the element itself which indentifies as vector/point, but its membership to a space. If you consider $\Bbb R^3$ with vector space structure then call the element vector, if you consider $\Bbb R^3$ with affine structure, then call it a point. You simply cannot know what it is if you not stated yourself what you consider the surrounding space to be.

Comment: @M.Winter yes, you understand me correctly. So now, I am considering the second option. $M$ is a point in an affine space. I am also saying that $\mathbf{dM}$ is a vector. In the second equation in my initial post, if the left hand side term (that is $\mathbf{dM}$) is a vector, something on the right hand side should be a vector as well. Which quantity is a vector then?

Comment: @pluton I would say $\partial M/\partial q_i$. I would also disagree to call $\partial\mathbf r$ vector-valued because the symbol $\partial\mathbf r$ makes no sense outside the notation $\partial\mathbf r/\partial q_i$. So the last term is the actually vector-valued one.

Comment: @M.Winter You might want to provide an answer that I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that $\partial \mathbf M/\partial q^i$ carries the vector structure of the second equation's right hand side as it embodies a *change* in an affine space (which is of vector character by nature).

Actually, I would disagree to call $\partial\mathbf r$ vector-valued because the symbol $\partial\mathbf r$ itself has no meaning outside of the notation $\partial\mathbf r/\partial q^i$. Instead the latter term is the actually vector-valued one in your first equation.